# How to access file with lambda function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless

Problem I recently switch in serverless architecture and I cannot be able to access my file Below code run fine in local environment but it not execute in lambda function it give me following error

It give me following error

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open &#39;tmp/file 1-1692962065917.pdf&#39;
```

Can you guide me how can I access file in lambda function

Here is my code

```
const serverless = require("serverless-http");
const express = require("express");
const multer = require('multer');
const fs = require('fs');
const { PDFDocument } = require('pdf-lib');
const http = require('http');
// const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

const os = require('os');
const cluster = require('cluster');
const { default: e } = require('express');
const path = require('path');


// count total number of cpu
const cpuNums = os.cpus().length;
console.log("Total Number of Cpus(CORS):"+cpuNums);

var date = new Date();

const app = express();
var check=0;



app.use(cors({
  origin: '*',
}));



var fname;


// Set up multer to handle file uploads
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
         cb(null, './tmp/');
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    check++;
         fname = `${file.fieldname} ${check}-${Date.now()}.pdf`;
         console.log("Filename : "+fname);
         cb(null, fname);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });



app.post('/', upload.single('file'), (req, res,next) => { console.log("=================================================");
console.log("API Last Build Date " + date.toLocaleDateString());
console.log("API Last Build  Time" + date.toLocaleTimeString());

console.log(date.getFullYear()+'-'+(date.getMonth()+1)+'-'+date.getDate());
console.log("===========================");

console.log("LAST API CALL TIME:--" + date.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata' }));

console.log("===========================");
console.log("Your IP Addresss is: " + req.socket.localAddress);
console.log("=================================================");
    // Read the input PDF file
    const file = req.file;
    if (!file) {
           const error = new Error("Please upload a file");
           error.httpStatusCode = 400;
           return next(error);
    }
    // crop uploaded file

    async function cropPDF(inputPath, outputPath, x, y, width, height) {
           // Read the input PDF file
           let pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(fs.readFileSync(inputPath));

           //   Loop through all pages in the PDF
           for (let i = 0; i < pdfDoc.getPages().length; i++) {


                  // Get the page that you want to crop
                  let page = pdfDoc.getPage(i);

                  // Set the crop box for the page
                  page.setCropBox(x, y, width, height);
           }
           // console.log();
           // Save the output PDF file
           fs.writeFileSync(outputPath, await pdfDoc.save());
           fs.unlink( './tmp/'+fname, (err) => {
                  if (err) {

                    console.error(err);


                  } else {
                    console.log('File deleted successfully');
                  }
                });


                res.download(outputPath);
           // fs.unlink();

    }

     if(req.body.Ecommerce==2)
    {

    cropPDF('./tmp/' + fname,'outputfiledownload.pdf', 170, 467, 255, 353)
           .then(() => {
                  console.log("PDF is cropped");
                  // PDF has been cropped
           })
           .catch((error) => {
                  console.log(error);
           });


    }
    });

    module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

Summary of a code:

I first user upload pdf and I save and then according to user choice I call function and do operation and after delete the file

Answer (score 1):

You need to change all your `./tmp` paths to `/tmp`. The `./tmp` path translates to "The `tmp` folder under the current directory", which in this case would the the directory that the Lambda function runs in. In the AWS Lambda environment you cannot write to the directory that the Lambda function runs in. You can only write to the `/tmp` directory.